# passing gridview particular row datas to another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i want to set session in login page and want to pass one page girdview data to another page.

```
slno  title     author    publication    takenby
  1    book1    author1   pub1           sendrequest (button)
```

Above image showing gridview. when i click the Request Book button(1st one). it will redirect to sendrequest.aspx page. and have to bring that row data (i.e)

```
slno=1
title=book1
Author=author1
publication=publ
```

i tried below code
user.aspx.cs

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                string user = (string)(Session["User"]);
                if (e.CommandName.Equals("SendRequestCmd"))
                {
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        Session["slno"] = null;
                        Session["bookname"] = null;
                        var clickedRow = ((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                        // now access the cells like this
                        SlNo = clickedRow.Cells[0].Text;
                        Session["slno"] = SlNo.ToString();
                        BookName = clickedRow.Cells[1].Text;
                        Session["bookname"] = BookName.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

sendquest.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string slno = "", bookname = "";
            slno = (string)(Session["slno"]);
            bookname = (string)(Session["bookname"]);
            if (slno == null || bookname == null)
            {
                Response.Write("serial no: " + slno + "\nbookname: " + bookname);
            }
        }
        protected void Logout()
        {
            Session.Clear();
        }
```

but i got error in

```
slno=(string)(Session["slno"]);
bookname=(string)(Session["bookname"]);
```

why? anybody correct it?
else say better way?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving for the Session objects?

Comment: instead of passing each value in a seprate session just create a type(Class) and each value as property and set object each property and pass that object in session and cast on receving end , easy to check session is null for a single session instead of 4-5 session values

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your error it's difficult to see what the problem is. You could check that Sessions are enabled in your application.

Another way to do this (which may be better) is passing just the id/slno (via QueryString) to your other page, then perform a lookup to get your data at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

I will surely create a type(Class) for booking

with  `slno  title     author    publication` properties and

```
public class Booking
{
    public Booking()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public int slno { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string publication { get; set; }

}
```

set all properties of  object of booking type and pass that object in session

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string user = (string)(Session["User"]);
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("SendRequestCmd"))
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                Booking b = new Booking();
                b.slno = clickedRow.Cells[0].Text;
                b.Title = BookName.ToString();

                Session["Booing"] = b;

            }
        }
    }
```

and on receiving end just case that session value into that object again 
and access each property just by using dot with object name .

```
   Booking b=(Booking)Session["Booking"]
       int slno=b.slno;
    string Title=b.Title;
```

Without posting error not possible to give suggestion or correction  , my answer is just how can you pass multiple values using session from one page to another .

Thanks